# Not able to see my token on metamask

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, truffle, remix, metamask

This is my complete contract code :
https://gist.github.com/cmaliwal/31a80d36b8d873a3dca37b2b18188164

When I deployed my contract on `ropsten` test network using `remix` and `metamask` contract deployed successfully.

[image: DEPLOY CONTRACT ON ROPSTEN]

When I am trying to add token on metmask , I am getting `0 TKN` instead of my token (DEV).

[image: Add tokens on metmask]

[image: Token details]

transaction address : [Tx. on etherscan](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xf88307f5facb37a88350eb0259727110e93f80c6da8265735f0625f334badaa4)

contract address :  [contract on etherscan](http://0x9f99A7A783a951E52F6Ff07E1B72aE1e19610fEd)

Comment: Did you transfer some tokens from your contract to your personnal address ?

Comment: No ! I didn't transfer any tokens.
As you can see on my code, DEV is mintable token (the total supply of the token starts with 0 and increases as people purchase the tokens in the crowdsale)
Let's think I have 0 DEV token but it showing me 0 TKN.

Comment: So you need to call `buyTokens(address)`

Comment: @chiragmaliwal Your error is that you are registering the crowdsale contract in metamask and you have to register the token contract which is created in the constructor `token = new DeveloperToken()`. To obtain the token address you have to call `crowdsale.token.call()`.

Comment: How can I show how much DEV token I have in my wallent and also my contract is related to ERC20 ?

Comment: Try to give separate answer so I upvote and accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor function in the crowdsale is misspelled

edit:  Thanks Ismael for the solidity update syntax.

Comment: No, new version of solidity compiler the constructor function has new syntax `constructor(params) { /* body */ }`

Comment: That is one of the issues. Please edit your answer to add that.

Comment: Cheers, just edited it

Comment: It's just typo !! Thanks for the update , I updated the code .

Comment: this is not the reason of error.